# how to create shifted color scale ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a continous variable that I would like to map to the color of my points.
However the distribution of the variable is shifted tot the right.

So I thought I could use the quantiles to set the breaks but this doesn't seem to be working.

I think I don't understand the subtleties between all of the different variants of `scale_colour_gradient`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = LibPl, y = IntStd, color = totSmpInt)) +
  geom_point(position = "jitter", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(n = 4, "RdYlBu"),
                         breaks = c(qn[1], qn[2], qn[3], qn[4], qn[5]))
```

[image]

As you can see from the color legend in the plot it doesn't really seem like the quantiles were used as break points.

I have read a few other similar posts, and tried variants, but none are working
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you color using log scale ??

Comment: the numbers are allready logged

Comment: [Consider providing a reproducible example to recreate your problem or intended task.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a normal behavior : the scale is extended from minimum to maximum value. One solution would be to reassign all values below the first quintile to that value : `df$totSmpInt[df$totSmpInt < qn[1]] <- qn[1]` (or to a slightly lower value `df$totSmpInt[df$totSmpInt < qn[1]] <- qn[1] * 0.95` so they don't distort the scale so much